# Calculate value in codeigniter from mysql database

Tags: php, codeigniter, calculation

I just jump in codeigniter where I believe it so hard to learn in Model and Controller but where Viewes is good. I am facing an issue to creating a calculation (adding +) function in codeigniter.

Actually in my database I save the values like this:-

```
-------------------------------------------
ID  |  Name      |  Amount   |  DATE
-------------------------------------------
01  | Product 1  |  $250     | 20/09/1996
02  | Product 2  |  $200     | 20/09/1996
03  | Product 3  |  $210     | 20/09/1996
04  | Product 4  |  $260     | 20/09/1996
05  | Product 5  |  $280     | 20/09/1996
```

I want add all amount value so that I created this code and added in model

```
public function countTotalToday()
    {
        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Mumbai');
        $now = date('d-m-Y');
        //$sql = "SELECT amount FROM orders_item WHERE date = '$now'";
        $sql = "sum(amount) from order_item where date(dateCol)=date(now())";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        //return $query->num_rows();
    }
```

and in controller i make like this

```
$this->data['total_paisa'] = $this->model_brands->countTotalToday();
```

and in Views

```
<h3 style="display:inline;"><?php echo $total_paisa ?></h3><h5 style="display:inline; vertical-align:center;">(Sleep <?php echo $total_paisa ?>)</h5>
```

But the code says error 500, I don't know i fixed this, could you help me how oi make the code which works to calculate the value as amount and echo me in views with calculation in Adding method.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Do you get any errors? Add [error reporting](//php.net/manual/function.error-reporting.php) at the top of your file(s): `ini_set("display_errors", 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` and tell us what you get.

Comment: in codeigniter where i edit your code to show error and is my code above is right?

Comment: https://arjunphp.com/error-reporting-handling-in-codeigniter/ (Also, please don't type in all caps. It signifies that you're shouting, which is not something you want to do to users who are trying to help you)

Comment: You do not have a `date` column in your table. So why are you using it in `where` condition?

Comment: I am sorry but i forget to update date in post but really i have in DB

Answer (score 0):

According to your provided table data you don't have `date` column. So no need to add `where` condition

Try like this

```
public function countTotalToday()
{
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Mumbai');
    $now = date('d-m-Y');
    $this->db->select('SUM(amount) AS amount');
    $qwer = $this->db->get('order_item')->result();
}
```

If you want to add the condition. Use this

```
$this->db->where('column-name', $value);
```

Comment: What i do for echo like this `<h3 style="display:inline;"><?php echo $total_paisa ?></h3><h5 style="display:inline; vertical-align:center;">(Sleep <?php echo $total_paisa ?>)</h5>`